# Convert Tensorflow1.12 model to Tensorflow Lite (TFLite)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to convert a model that I created in Tensorflow 1.12 to Tensorflow Lite.

I use this Code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Generate tf.keras model.
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, input_shape=(3,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(3))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)))
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MSE,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.0001),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.categorical_accuracy],
              sample_weight_mode='temporal')

x = np.random.random((1, 3))
y = np.random.random((1, 3, 3))
model.train_on_batch(x, y)
model.predict(x)

# Save tf.keras model in HDF5 format.
keras_file = "keras_model.h5"
tf.keras.models.save_model(model, keras_file)

# Convert to TensorFlow Lite model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_file)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

I took this Code example from the website https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/r1/convert/python_api.md#pre_tensorflow_1.12.
Because I am using Tensorflow 1.12 I modified the line

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_file)
```

to

```
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_file)
```

as suggested in the link above.
When I ran this Code I got this info:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Froze 4 variables.
INFO:tensorflow:Converted 4 variables to const ops.
```

Afterwards I got this error:

---

```
------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-81a9e7060f2c> in <module>
     23 # Convert to TensorFlow Lite model.
     24 converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(keras_file)
---> 25 tflite_model = converter.convert()
     26 open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\lite\python\lite.py in convert(self)
    451           input_tensors=self._input_tensors,
    452           output_tensors=self._output_tensors,
--> 453           **converter_kwargs)
    454     else:
    455       # Graphs without valid tensors cannot be loaded into tf.Session since they

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\lite\python\convert.py in toco_convert_impl(input_data, input_tensors, output_tensors, *args, **kwargs)
    340   data = toco_convert_protos(model_flags.SerializeToString(),
    341                              toco_flags.SerializeToString(),
--> 342                              input_data.SerializeToString())
    343   return data
    344 

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow1.12\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\lite\python\convert.py in toco_convert_protos(model_flags_str, toco_flags_str, input_data_str)
    133     else:
    134       raise RuntimeError("TOCO failed see console for info.\n%s\n%s\n" %
--> 135                          (stdout, stderr))
    136 
    137 

RuntimeError: TOCO failed see console for info.
b'C:\\Users\\.\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow1.12\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\framework\\dtypes.py:523: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or \'1type\' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / \'(1,)type\'.\r\n  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])\r\nC:\\Users\\.\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow1.12\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\framework\\dtypes.py:524: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or \'1type\' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / \'(1,)type\'.\r\n  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])\r\nC:\\Users\\.\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow1.12\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\framework\\dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or \'1type\' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / \'(1,)type\'.\r\n  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])\r\nC:\\Users\\.\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow1.12\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\framework\\dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or \'1type\' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / \'(1,)type\'.\r\n  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])\r\nC:\\Users\\.\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow1.12\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\framework\\dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or \'1type\' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / \'(1,)type\'.\r\n  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])\r\nC:\\Users\\.\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow1.12\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\python\\framework\\dtypes.py:532: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or \'1type\' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / \'(1,)type\'.\r\n  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "C:\\Users\\.\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow1.12\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\contrib\\lite\\toco\\python\\tensorflow_wrap_toco.py", line 18, in swig_import_helper\r\n    fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(\'_tensorflow_wrap_toco\', [dirname(__file__)])\r\n  File "C:\\Users\\.\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow1.12\\lib\\imp.py", line 297, in find_module\r\n    raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)\r\nImportError: No module named \'_tensorflow_wrap_toco\'\r\n\r\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\r\n\r\nTraceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File "C:\\Users\\.\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow1.12\\Scripts\\toco_from_protos-script.py", line 6, in <module>\r\n    from tensorflow.contrib.lite.toco.python.toco_from_protos import main\r\n  File "C:\\Users\\.\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow1.12\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\contrib\\lite\\toco\\python\\toco_from_protos.py", line 22, in <module>\r\n    from tensorflow.contrib.lite.toco.python import tensorflow_wrap_toco\r\n  File "C:\\Users\\.\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow1.12\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\contrib\\lite\\toco\\python\\tensorflow_wrap_toco.py", line 28, in <module>\r\n    _tensorflow_wrap_toco = swig_import_helper()\r\n  File "C:\\Users\\.\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow1.12\\lib\\site-packages\\tensorflow\\contrib\\lite\\toco\\python\\tensorflow_wrap_toco.py", line 20, in swig_import_helper\r\n    import _tensorflow_wrap_toco\r\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named \'_tensorflow_wrap_toco\'\r\n'
None

Could someone help to solve this?
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use newer tensorflow and use its new converter (called MLIR, not TOCO).

Tried your code with 2.4.0 (but will work with [2.2.x](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert) as well) and a bit modified line:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
```

and obtained *.tflite model.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but I need Tensorflow 1.12 for specific hardware. In Tensorflow 2.2 it works for me, too but not in 1.12

Comment: May you please share TOCO output? Skim through error log, it should be there.

Comment: I added the detailed error message in my initial question. I hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like this is your issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22897 . Try to update your tensorflow 1.12

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experiments, the tf2.x is friendlier with keras and can have you quantize flawlessly. But to tf1.x you should switch to export to QAT or frozen graph def to ensure the quantization.
For the QAT: you can check in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r1.15/tensorflow/contrib/quantize)

Comment: Thank you, QAT looks interesting. But my first goal is not to quantize the model. At first, I just want to convert my model from TF to TFLite without quantization, just in floating32. And this doesn't work right now in Tensorflow 1.12.

Comment: Can you test on tf1.15? It is much stable version